# Formatting PHP with CSS trouble

Tags: php, css

What is wrong with this code that the PHP will not show now that I added the css?

```
$args = array(       
'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',     
 'meta_value' => 0,   
 );    
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );   
 $users = $user_query->get_results();    

 foreach( $users as $user ):      
echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">"$user->display_name"</div>";    
 echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">will be celebrating their anniversary on </div>";       
echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">" get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'anniversary_date', true )"</div>";     
 endforeach;
```

Comment: I can't seem to find your CSS. Could you point out what you changed to break any working code?

Comment: Also, you should have `.` inbetween quotes and variables to concatenate the string.

Comment: Yes, it's like concatenation is missing where necessary

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',     
    'meta_value' => 0  
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );   
$users = $user_query->get_results();    

foreach( $users as $user ) {
    echo '<div class="anniversary-output">'.$user->display_name.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="anniversary-output">will be celebrating their anniversary on</div>';       
    echo '<div class="anniversary-output">'.get_user_meta($user->ID,'anniversary_date',true).'</div>';     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of errors in your php:

The extra comma in the array & no concat `.`'s

```
<?php 
$args = array(       
'meta_key' => 'anniversary_date',     
'meta_value' => 0);    
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );   
$users = $user_query->get_results();    

 foreach( $users as $user ):      
   echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">".$user->display_name."</div>";    
   echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">will be celebrating their anniversary on </div>";       
   echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">".get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'anniversary_date', true )."</div>";     
 endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: some coding standards (e.g. drupal) recommends you put that extra comma

Comment: drupal is a perfect example of bad coding standards, that and wordpress, and trailing commas in arrays is perfectly valid but looks ugly and imo is bad practice, this is entirely for convenience so you can easily add another element to the array without having to first add the trailing comma to the last entry. yuk! http://bit.ly/LityQ3

Answer (score 0):

I have added concatenation. Try this

```
echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">".$user->display_name."</div>";    
echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">will be celebrating their anniversary on </div>";       
echo "<div class=\"anniversary-output\">".get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'anniversary_date', true )."</div>";
```